# Share data between two ASP.NET MVC apps on same server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-transfer

I have an ASP.NET MVC app running on the root of my web server.  I have created another MVC app that will run as a separate app under the root app.  I will be doing a server.transfer from one app to the other and this seems to work fine. However, I need to do a database lookup in the first app and then transfer. I do not want to have to do another database lookup in the second app if I can help it.

Do I have access to any storage such as Context.Items, etc that I can use to pass data to the app that I transfer to? I have tried using Context.Items and it does not work. Any research I've done has had mixed reviews.  Are there any options besides using a key and doing a second database lookup after I transfer to the second app?  I'm using ASP.NET MVC and C#.

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that you are crossing AppDomains.  If your data is small enough, could you pass it in the URL when you call Server.Transfer.

Comment: Are you using sql server?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, I don't believe this can work when it is hosted across multiple domain (as said by David it crosses Application Domains and websites as well). When you have it inside the same domain as  a sub-folder it still runs in the same context of the app domain.

The alternative would be to use a Cache servers like memcached, couchbase or a database. Or you can get or post the values as variables through HTTP request.